# Getting the path of ALL the files dropped onto a Mac's dock icon

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, dock, nsapplication

I'm trying to use the `NSApplicationDelegate` and the `openFiles` method to try grabbing the path of a list of random files users would drop on my (Cocoa) App's dock icon.

My solution works flawlessly when dragging single files or folders onto my app's dock icon.

However, it often fails to perform its job when multiple files or folders are dragged onto the icon. When doing so, `openFiles` is always called but, often, the list of files it provides isn't complete. Passing the same files separately works perfectly.

Does someone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong?

(I'm on Snow Leopard 10.6.8)

--

**UPDATE**: I've uploaded a test program reproducing the issue here: https://fgt.bo/if6

Is there something wrong with my plist file?

Comment: no idea without seeing your code...

Comment: So, you sometimes get all the files, and other times just some of them? Are the files of the same type?

Comment: No, files aren't of the same type. And I didn't find any rational relation between files I get in the list and files that won't show yet. I'll update my question with a clean code example as soon as possible.

Comment: @KenAspeslagh Okay. I finally uploaded my code. Thanks for helping me!